# Representativeness of population by a sample population

Tags: mean

given a population mean and a sample mean of size N=108, based only on this attribute how can we conclude that this sample is representative of the population?

Comment: Because "representative" has many interpretations, please tell us what you mean by it.

Comment: It is hard to understand "a sample population" when sample and population were put together. . Is it sample, or is it population"?

Answer (score 1):

Let's put it this way - you cannot conclude from a sample number (e.g., sample size N = 108) whether or not the sample itself is representative of the population (i.e., the sample captures the salient features of the population).  You would need to know HOW the sample was selected from the population in order to make that determination, rather than HOW BIG the sample is. If the sample was selected as a convenience sample, for example, than it is highly unlikely that it is representative of the underlying population.

Comment: actually Iam trying to understand what is being asked in this question:                
   Q.The average revenue per transaction in the population is Rs 614. Based on this attribute only, would you be confident that this sample is representative of the population?

Hint: Is the sample average different from the population average? If yes, how different based on statistical significance? Please note that sample size > 100.And what is the p value of the hypothesis.(i found the average of sample is 590).

Comment: now that we know both the averages how do we know the representativeness of the population by the sample and what test do we use to calculate the p value say at 5% level of significance?

Comment: My answer to the original question still stands - representativeness of a sample is ensured by how a sample was selected.  You need to post your new question separately.